# Is there a way to enable offline persistence for only one collection, but not other collection?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections set up in my Firestore database:

```
let COLLECTION_POSTS = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
let COLLECTION_USERS = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
```

In `COLLECTION_POSTS`, users' social posts (e.g. Facebook-style post) will be saved. It can have pictures, so I would not want to let these posts be cached locally. However, I would allow data from `COLLECTION_USERS` be cached. It does not take up much space in hard drive anyway.

So I wrote a code like this in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
        
COLLECTION_POSTS.firestore.settings = settings
```

But I am met with this error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Firestore instance has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only set settings before calling any other methods on a Firestore instance.'

Is there any way to selectively deny offline persistence for each collection in Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible to control the cache on a per-collection level. Disk based persistence is either on or off, with nothing in between.

You *could* use two separate instances of the `Firestore.firestore()` object, as shown in the documentation on [accessing multple projects in your application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects?authuser=0#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application). You'd have two `FirebaseOptions`/`FirebaseApp`/`Firestore` instances for the same project, and enable caching on one and not on the other. But you may get into a pretty tricky situation to keep the documents from the different instances in sync.

---

On the exception itself:

The exception is pretty clear: you're trying to modify the settings after the client has already been initialized.

You'll need to set `firebase.firestore.settings` before you first call `firestore()`. For example, this would be fine:

```
let settings = FirestoreSettings()
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
Firestore.firestore.settings = settings
let COLLECTION_POSTS = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
let COLLECTION_USERS = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
```

---