# How do I specify what part of Firestore dataset to cache on the local machine?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, persistence

I have a large collection at the root of my Firestore database (representing all the icons from Material Icons that the user can use for a task).

[image]

Now this data is needed on my front-end application, how do I tell firebase to cache this specific collection (that is not subject to changes) on the local in-memory as to persist it between application refreshes?

**Note**: I am using Firebase V9

Comment: Are you looking for [configuring cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_cache_size)?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thanks for your answer. What I need is selective caching. I don't really care pulling user's data every refresh but this icons set is huge and I want to prioritize this data caching over any other structure.

Comment: You can't cache only selected collections directly. However, you can try creating multiple instances of Firebase app as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68901352/13130697). Or if the data rarely changes, I would just use local storage or any equivalent and update it based on some flag stored in DB.

Comment: @Dharmaraj by some flag you mean a hashtag that I compare when the app opens?

Comment: For example, store the timestamp of when the data was last updated locally and in realtime database. If the timestamp is updated in database, that will not match local timestamp and then you can manually update the local dataset. (like only query the documents that were updated again by comparing the timestamps) You can modify the logic based on your use case. I would just store this data as a JSON file tbh and update periodically. A cloud function that updates this JSON while every now and then. That'll save even more reads in future if your data set grows.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to use [Cloud Firestore data bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles).

Excerpts from the doc:

> Cloud Firestore data bundles are **static data files** built by you from
> Cloud Firestore document and query snapshots, and published by you on
> a CDN, hosting service or other solution. Data bundles include **both
> the documents you want to provide to your client apps and metadata
> about the queries that generated them**. You use client SDKs to download
> bundles over the network or from local storage, after which **you load
> bundle data to the Cloud Firestore local cache**. Once a bundle is
> loaded, **a client app can query documents from the local cache** or the
> backend.

See also this other [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles) of the Firestore documentation.